# grouping item and count in data using loop

Tags: php, symfony

I have a data when i do

> var_dump ($data);

here is how my data is displayed ($data is not a table balise):

```
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| adan  | Afla     | avo       | 0             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| adan  | ken      | joly      | 0             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| busia | koko     | ho        | 0             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| busia | koko     | ho        | 0             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| busia | koko     | ho        | 0             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

however, I would like the table display to become :

```
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| adan  | Afla     | avo       | 1             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| adan  | ken      | joly      | 1             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| busia | koko     | ho        | 3             |
+-------+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

here is my code :

```
foreach($data as $liste){
    $town[]=$liste->getLocalite()->getName();
    $counties[]=$liste->getCountie()->getName();
    $districts[]=$liste->getDistrict()->getName();;
}

$a= count($listforages)-1;
$numberDoc=0;
$tab1=$tab2=$tab3=$tab4=array();


    for ($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++){

$tab[$i]= $town[$i].'--'.$counties [$i].'--'.$districts[$i].'--'.$numberDoc[$i];

if( $i == $a  ) {

     if ($counties [$a-1]==$counties [$a] && $districts[$a-1]==$districts[$a]  && $numberDoc[$a-1]==$numberDoc[$a] ){
        $numberDoc[$a]++; //  counter
        $tab1[$a-1]=$town[$a-1].'--'.$counties [$a-1].'--'.$districts[$a-1].'--'. $numberDoc[$a-1];
     }

     if ($counties [$a-1] !=$counties [$a] && $districts[$a-1] !=$districts[$a]  && $numberDoc[$a-1] !=$numberDoc[$a] ){
    $numberDoc[$a]++; //  counter
      $tab2[$a-1]=$town[$a-1].'--'.$counties [$a-1].'--'.$districts[$a-1].'--'. $numberDoc[$a-1];
     }
}   
 else{
    if ($counties [$i]==$counties [$i+1] && $districts[$i]==$districts[$i+1]  && $numberDoc[$i]==$numberDoc[$i+1] ){
      $numberDoc[$i]++; //  counter
      $tab3[$i]=$town[$i].'--'.$counties [$i].'--'.$districts[$i].'--'. $numberDoc[$i];
     }

    if ($counties [$i] !=$counties [$i+1] && $districts[$i] !=$districts[$i+1]  && $numberDoc[$i] !=$numberDoc[$i+1] ){
        $numberDoc[$i]++; //  counter
      $tab4[$i]=$town[$i].'--'.$counties [$i].'--'.$districts[$i].'--'. $numberDoc[$i];
     }
}



}
```

when you see my data (see table) :

town is column 0, 
counties is  column 1, 
district is  column 2, 
numberDoc is column 3 ,

my code don't work ,How resolve this issue ?

NB: excuse my english,

thank you in advance

Comment: Is this in a DB? I think you could use `group by` and `count` to achieve this if so.

Comment: Is there any rule behind the expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you please provide the raw output from var_dump();

Comment: @Ash-b                                                                                                                       array (size=5)
  0 => string 'adan adan aflo 0' (length=16)
  1 => string 'adan ken joly 0' (length=15)
  2 => string 'busia koko ho 0' (length=15)
  3 => string 'busia koko ho 0' (length=15)
  4 => string 'busia koko ho 0' (length=15)

Comment: @ user3783243 , i would like use the output

Comment: This requires a _control break_ - very basic principle, that every programmer should know. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break

Comment: @04FS, ok  thank , but how use _control break_ in my code ?

Comment: Step 1: Understand how it basically works, step 2: Implement it … (Not going to do that for you; make your own attempt first, and ask if you have any _specific_ problem with it.)

Comment: @04FS ok , I will try this